# Bypass the Wordpress Template Entirely

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

I'm writing a simple plugin to take a specialized URI, run a specialized wp_query, and return JSON. As a result, I want to bypass all of the standard WordPress template system. My current method is to hook into the 'wp' action, do the query, print the JSON, and then die(), but this bypasses the caching system.

I'd like to run my custom query, output the JSON, and then tell Wordpress to skip over everything else in its lifecycle and immediately do the 'shutdown' action so that the JSON request can be cached for the next time.

I can't find anything in the codex that allows me to completely bypass the template system and jump to the shutdown action. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "template_include" hook.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

It is run immediately before the template file is included.